# Need to make a "bulletproof" div

Tags: html

How do i make a div that will not break even if the structure of the information inside it is improperly made.

ie:

```
<div id="bulletproof_div">
    <div> </div>
    <div> </div>
    <div id="unclosed_div">
</div>

<div id="normally_this_one_would_break">
</div>
```

edit: the context is that it is a mailing system where i have no control over the information that is being sent to me, that is why i need to make it so that the website will not break.

i have tried successfully with iframe but i need to be able to modify the inner html of the div so iframe is not ideal.

Thank you for reading

Comment: you can use another tag besides 'div'?

Comment: This is such a weird use case. You need to be able to modify the html, but you are admitting the HTML might be bad? Do you have control over the incoming HTML?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve here? That may help more with solutions.

Comment: @thatidiotguy i have edited to answer you question

Comment: @Eric yes i definitely try other tags im just not sure which one would be best for the behavior that i need.

Comment: Bulletproof? OK, how's this. Take the incoming information, parse it with an error-correcting (i.e. tag-soup-aware) parser, serialise the resulting DOM tree. Done. Be aware though that in your specific example, the bottommost div would end up inside the first div.

Comment: @bouteillebleu i have edited to answer you question

Answer (score 2):

Iframes are the only 100% bullet-proof containers to isolate contents from the surrounding page.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the broken markup before it is appended to the 'bulletproof_div' you can use this function to 'fix' the markup before it is appended

```
function cleanMarkup(markupStr) {
    // temp 'div' only used as a container, it is not returned with output
    var temp = document.createElement("div");
    temp.innerHTML = markupStr;
    return temp.innerHTML;
}
```

Most browsers will attempt to fix broken markup, so when you retrieve the `innerHTML` property  immediately after setting it, the value will be a 'fixed' markup string.

So given this input

```
cleanMarkup("<div></div> <div id='unclosed'>test!")
```

The function should return

```
<div></div> <div id="unclosed">test!</div>
```

Comment: +1 Pretty standard approach. jQuery does this internally to keep user-submitted markup clean.